# Creating new Windows Phone App project: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error (WP8 SDK, VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, project

I have VS2012 Pro Update 3. I've downloaded and installed Windows Phone 8 SDK to create Windows Phone apps for the latest MS smartphone OS (WP8). However, I get the above-mentioned error when I try to create a new Windows Phone App project.

I deinstalled and reinstalled WP8 SDK as suggested on many forums and blogs, and even used the "repair installation" mode for VS2012 and WP8 SDK, but all this did not help.

How to get rid of this error?

---

P.S. My pc has Windows 8 Pro 64-bit and the CPU supports Hyper-V needed for this development (added this optional component to my Windows successfully). Other common Windows projects, such as WinForms and WPF apps, can be created and compiled without any problems in my dev env.

Comment: When you are getting this error ? While creating an app or while debugging ?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq, I open the New Project dialog, type in project name, hit OK - and the error message box appears. After I close it, I see no new project in VS. Just an empty folder with the project name is created on my drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my puzzle using the trial and errors method. Go to the TOOLS menu, then choose 'Extensions and Updates', then the Update section and install the latest NuGet update. Funny, yes?

Answer (score 1):

My Solution: **UNINSTALLED** NuGet (as updates to it did not work)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed visual studio 2012 update 3.

Go to the TOOLS menu, then choose 'Extensions and Updates', then the Update section and install visual studio update.

Comment: As you can see in my case, I already had the Update 3 installed, so it didn't help me.