# Object reference is not set to an instance of an object on creating windows phone app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

When i tried to create a windows phone application on visual studio 2012 i get the error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object".  I searched on google and find that deleting the 'NuGet packet manager' will solve the issue. But after deleting the packet manager i got the same error. What should i do to create the app.?

Comment: could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289594/creating-new-windows-phone-app-project-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

it appears that your windows phone development kit along with your visual studio is messed up. Try running the Visual Studio setup again and choose repair your installation. Once done, try creating the windows app again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your `Windows phone SDK` toolkit or repair it. If still your are getting same issue try to repair your `visual studio 2012` from `control panel`.

**Note:** Please close your visual studio before repair.

Comment: After reinstalling windows phone SDK and visual studio also getting the same error.

Comment: When you are getting this? I mean it is at the time of creating new project?

Comment: Go to the TOOLS menu, then choose 'Extensions and Updates', then the Update section and install the latest NuGet update

Comment: I already done these updates. but no use, still getting the error

Comment: Ok I think you need uninstall `VS` and `WP SDK` and re-install it again.

Comment: I already unistall and re-install both the products, still getting the error